# running python script with argparser

Tags: python, argparse

Trying to run my script using argparser, where the program does not run, unless correct argument is in place, however it does not seem to work;

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'
```

```py
import sys
import argparse

from develop import Autogit as gt



def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    # Create argument command
    parser_update = subparsers.add_parser('--sync', help='Sync local and remote repos')
    parser_update.set_defaults(func=gt.run)

    # Adding arguments
    parser.add_argument('--sync', type=str, required=True)

    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        sys.argv.append('--help')

    options = parser.parse_args()
    options.func()   # <--- Causes the error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also when the --sync arg is given it ask for another, then when I add one more argument. SYNC, then it returns attribute error.

### Edit

Trying to make the program run the develop.Autogit.run

### Working..

Had to also add args as argument in the run funciton i am calling.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: options.func() also updated the question

Comment: Is the `&lt;` really in your code?  If so, replace with `<`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `options.func()`?

Comment: that was my bad, when copying over it happened. but it is not &lt

Comment: @Code-Apprentice trying to run the function?

Comment: Please describe how you would like to use the program, i.e. how would you like to invoke it on the command line and what would you expect to happen in the program (i.e. which function executed).

Comment: It's a good idea to include a `print(options)` line before you try to use any the attributes.  That will show you what the parser has found - including attribute names and values.  If those values don't make sense, or something is missing, then you need to correct the parser setup (and/or the commandline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is setting a default, typically this is done with [`ArgumentParser.set_defaults()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults). You need to do this with the uninitialised function. See this example:

```py
import sys
import argparse

def f(args):
    print("In func")
    print(args)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    # Create argument command
    parser_update = subparsers.add_parser("sync", help="Sync local and remote repos")

    parser_update.set_defaults(func=f)  # <-- notice it's `f` not `f()`

    options = parser.parse_args()
    options.func(options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As an aside, you will have more problems with your snippet as you are defining the same parameter (`--sync`) in multiple places. When using `subparsers` it is customary to make these positional (no leading `--`) so they act as subcommands.

---

Here is a typical command line that I would use with subcommands:

```py
import sys
import argparse

def f(args):
    print("In func f")
    print(args)

def g(args):
    print("In func g")
    print(args)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")

    parser_update = subparsers.add_parser("sync", help="Sync local and remote repos")
    parser_update.set_defaults(func=f)

    parser_delete = subparsers.add_parser("delete", help="Delete sub-command")
    parser_delete.set_defaults(func=g)

    options = parser.parse_args()
    if options.command is not None:
        options.func(options)
    else:
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This does not solve the error that the OP is asking about: https://replit.com/@codeguru/OrderlyAccomplishedUserinterface

Comment: [Take a look here](https://tio.run/##PY7BCoMwEETvfkXIxQjqoe1VSo@99V6KrCTGQE3CbqS0P5/GEDwN7My@Gf8Ni7PnGM3qHQYGqD0gqarKgmw4Tv0N9bYqGx7ZEU2J9CDlCMUTddfNztWHSSqMUs2wvQOJCXC4nFo2wW@oJ5BaYUo6H4yzlKrKT5YdSeLJM4@3jH8WhYrByu4pR2SsThxkDnfclb9SJZq0oOCaGP8). `bar` and `bax` are _never_ passed on the CLI

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. What happens if you do `print(options.bar)` in your example? Will we get a similar error?

Comment: Using `set_defaults` adds attributes to the parser that are typically unavailable to the command line; as in this case most often they are used for a nice interface. In the TIO example you can access the attrs `bar` and `baz` as though they were normally received on the CLI.

Comment: [Here is that line added](https://tio.run/##XY4xC8IwEIX3/oqQpSnYDupaxNHNXaRcSZoGbBIuKaJ/Pl5D6OD0uHvvvnf@E2dnTymZxTuMDFB7wKCqKguyfl91V9Tromy8Z0c0JdKBlAMUT9RtOzlX72ZQcZBqgvUVgxgB@/PxwEb49vUIUiukpPPROBuoqtxk2ZBBPHjm8QPj71mhYrCwG@VCMFYTB5nDDXfhT6pEQx8U3N/YUbZJ6Qc)

Comment: Ok, I'm with you. My previous assertions were incorrect. The part I can't understand is the code from your answer here still giving me a `AttributeError`. How come? That's the part I'm trying to reconcile.

Comment: That is due to using the subparser, see my updated example for how you can run these by setting and checking for the value of the subcommand. Essentially we are only setting the function on the subparser, so when you invoke your example there is no subcommand given (and so `func` is never set).

Comment: If you [play around with this example](https://tio.run/##jVLJbsMgEL3zFSN6KJaSXHqr6kOlXnqr1A8g1ICDZBYBlpqvd1kcx1bTKlxgZt57zObO8WTN0zQp7ayPEM4BzU/me8d8EAhxIcFY2mlOisfvcjA0zwjScV6ZSPC7ATmabgbipsYK/FAg9CQGRzZ@8a1i8pQP5B3a8iJb3AWHKru/g93/ydZMGXIhFR1ol/oPr74ftTDxo0S2FQQRaVJg4xADyb@0tf4KCuNXxYWkNzMY5/TqJ1yE2OLOas1M7tpKnI6OsygS9Yov9PomOJxNh3eQ@9riz2TAYDs2QFICL7RNXC@cDZthzKo3MpcNwAO87PdphlF1AlR8DHCUx2ynmzTHTXpcDOK/9Gp8SfCtwhN4fy33l9yNvPq5K9ZFZc2qleWieZBkPdkZ16xJh6y07MiCQEoCpYZpQSm0LWBK8y5Qiusy1MVA0/QD)

Comment: You can add arguments adding `sync` or `delete` will change the function that is invoked. In this link I set a default on the base `parser` but I prefer not to do this as it's easier for me to just see the conditional.